# Android's alarm manager wrong period

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating AlarmManager for my app in order to send sms messages in different periods. When I put a time for AlarmManager for example 5 minutes, it wakes up almost immediately about 1-2 times, but after this it works correct. After I change value of period the situatuion repeats. I think this is something wrong with stopping AlarmManager or with setting a repeater.

This is my `makeAlarm` function:

```
  private void makeAlarm() {
    cancelAlarm();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SmsAlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), SmsAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    SharedPreferences refreshSettings = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xd720p.sensorcontroller_09082016",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    double refreshForTValue = Double.valueOf(refreshSettings.getString("tempPeriod", "30"));

    if (refreshForTValue <= 0 ) {
        cancelAlarm();
    } else {
        long period = Math.round(refreshForTValue * 60 * 1000);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                firstMillis + period, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

This is my `cancelAlarm` function:

```
  private void cancelAlarm() {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SmsAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), SmsAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                i, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarm.cancel(pIntent);
        pIntent.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is my `SmsAlarmReceiver` class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
  public class SmsAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 322;


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsSenderService.class);
      context.startService(i);
  }
}
```

I create my alarm in `onCreate` method in `MainActivity`. Also I stop my alarm and making new, when I change period value. This value stores in `SharedPreferences`, so I tried to recreate alarm in `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, but it makes no sense in my situiation.

Comment: its not possible please check **refreshForTValue**  this value.May be problem is their

Comment: @Saveen this value is for checking if user put zero or less value for repeating. In this case i just kill AlarmManager. I don't think the problem is in **refreshForTValue**

Comment: setting on alarm is depends on this value.So, if it wrong or different as you think. It will give you different situation

Comment: @Saveen What could go wrong? I debugged this many times. If user set more than zero period, new alarm is set on (after stopping previous). If value is less than zero (or zero), alarm just stops.

Comment: okay your problem, alarm isn't repeated as you expected right ?

Comment: @Saveen yes. It fires about one-two times after starting app and then works correctly. Maybe I get curent time incorrectly?
`long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: yes right, only issue is setting of alaram not its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i solved it out! Here is my solution in `makeAlarm()` function:

```
    private void makeAlarm() {
    cancelAlarm();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SmsAlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), SmsAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    SharedPreferences refreshSettings = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xd720p.sensorcontroller_09082016",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    double refreshForTValue = 0;


    refreshForTValue = Double.valueOf(refreshSettings.getString("tempPeriod", "30"));


    if (refreshForTValue <= 0 ) {
        cancelAlarm();
    } else {
        long period = Math.round(refreshForTValue * 60 * 1000);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis + period,
                period, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

1. As you can see I changed `setRepeating()` arguments. The thing is that second argument not only for set start time of the period, but it wakes alarm up in the start time. So we need to add **period** value if we don't want to wake up alarm immediately. And the third argument is just a repetition period, so we need to remove start time. You can read about this in examples here:
   https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
2. In `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` we need to change flag from **FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** to **FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT**. I can't exactly explain why, but according to the documentation when we set **UPDATE** flag some of the changed properties will be ignored. Therefore alarm firstly will wake up in an old period. But **CANCEL_FLAG** allows us to replace properties and wake alarm up with new period. I'm sorry if my explanation is incorrect: as I said I didn't fully understand this moment. I will be glad if someone give good explanation.